# Setting BaseUrl on files loaded from Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, webview, wkwebview, base-url

This should probably be straightforward but it's been giving me a headache. 
Basically I'm creating an app that downloads a zip file containing html, css, javascript etc. 
It unzips the contents and stores them in LocalApplicationData, loades the index.html into a webview likes so:

```
HtmlWebViewSource html = new HtmlWebViewSource();

html.Html = htmlString;
html.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get().Get();
courseWindow.Source = html;
```

All of this works just fine, except I end with unformatted html, no scripts running etc..
I'm assuming this has to do with the baseURL but could it be something else like resources being blocked from loading?

If anybody has come upon the same issue or could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Here is what I have in my Android project.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl))]
namespace TCMobile.Droid
{
    public class BaseUrl : iBaseURL
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:/" + System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried to hard code the path to the exact directory the html is being loaded from.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl))]
namespace TCMobile.Droid
{
    public class BaseUrl : iBaseURL
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:/" + System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) +
                "Courses/2d7d0a7d-145a-41d0-9abf-685a2b5dfc3c/Online_Placement_Test_no_timer_pack/YKZOP4NACH3EPJNTG6M4T2BQDI/Unit_4_5/995/";
        }}
    }
```

With breakpoints I can see the path returned and it looks fine.

As a test I tried to pass an html string in with an iframe that had the source as my local html. This loaded the html fine, but gave me a bunch of cross domain issues with the js. Because the frames need to interact with each other. If I could get past the security issues with the iframe I'd be ok with that approach.

After more poking around I'm seeing this strangeness.

So this is strange. 
In iOS this is what I'm seeing

File Url - looks fine

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/04BFAB43-2D92-48D3-941D-C48C8686E0A5/Documents/Courses/2d7d0a7d-145a-41d0-9abf-685a2b5dfc3c/Online_Placement_Test_no_timer_pack/YKZOP4NACH3EPJNTG6M4T2BQDI/Unit_4_5/995/Unit.html/

BaseUrl looks fine

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/04BFAB43-2D92-48D3-941D-C48C8686E0A5/Documents/Courses/2d7d0a7d-145a-41d0-9abf-685a2b5dfc3c/Online_Placement_Test_no_timer_pack/YKZOP4NACH3EPJNTG6M4T2BQDI/Unit_4_5/995/

Included Js in web inspector - weird, notice how the html file name is added. Now this makes no since

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/04BFAB43-2D92-48D3-941D-C48C8686E0A5/Documents/Courses/2d7d0a7d-145a-41d0-9abf-685a2b5dfc3c/Online_Placement_Test_no_timer_pack/YKZOP4NACH3EPJNTG6M4T2BQDI/Unit_4_5/995/**Unit.html**/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Update:
I've changed how I'm loading the html to 
 Control.LoadFileUrl(fileUrl, fileUrl);

now the path to the referenced css and js looks correct  but they still don't load. 

I've tried both
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>    
  </dict>
and
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>    
  </dict>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've got the dependency service from the `WebView` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#local-html-content), so you're trying to configure `BaseUrl` correctly, and differently, on each platform.

Can you share your code for the dependency service? You'll have to make some changes from the [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithWebview) because it assumes your html, css, javascript is in the static resources for the app. You'll instead want to return the path to location where you've saved them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a NSAppTransportSecurity problem.
I've switched to the HybridWebview, and now the html loads fine in Android but still getting unformatted html in iOS.

If I pass in an incorrect base url the html does not load at all so this is why I'm leaning towards NSAppTransportSecurity

Even tried switching the render to LoadHtmlString, LoadFileUrl and LoadRequest. no luck.

Comment: It's possible to disable NSAppTransportSecurity checks via Info.plist -- have you tried that to verify your hypothesis?

Comment: Yep, tried every variation.
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>